# How can I prevent FTP users breaking chroot rules when using a GUI?

Tags: centos5, ftp

I've set up VSFTP on my Centos5.5 server.  I've created a user on the box for ftp access.  In the VSFTP config I've set:

```
chroot_list_enable=YES 
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
```

The conf file contains the username I created, so that the user is 'jail'ed to their home directory.  When I connect to the FTP server using the command line FTP program this rule is followed, ie I can't browse above the home directory.  However, when I connect using either Filezilla or gFTP I can browse above the home directory.  Also, when I try to connect with either of those GUIs using standard FTP I can't get a directory listing although I can get it when connecting using SFTP.  Could this be connected to the problem of the chroot being ignored?  And in either case, can anyone suggest how I would go about getting the chroot rule to be followed by these GUIs?

I also followed the instructions on this page (http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-open-ftp-port-21/) to open port 21 in the firewall, but it has made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out the previous 2 chroot_* lines and only leave this one enabled:

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

and see if it fixes your problem. Make sure that you also have local_enable=YES

Comment: @O G: Thanks for the suggestion.  I followed it and then restarted vsftpd, having made sure local_enable=YES was set, but it has made no difference

Comment: Do you have selinux enabled? (sestatus)

Comment: @O G: selinux is disabled: `SELinux status:                 disabled`

Comment: I just tested the scenario with chroot_local_user on my machine and I cannot replicate the behavior you describe with any client (tried: firefox,chrome,ncftp,gftp). vsftpd version here is 2.3.2 - what version are you using?

Comment: @O G: Sorry I havn'e replied, I've been off for the weekend. Anyway, I'm running version 2.0.5.  I'll upgrade to 2.3.2 and see what happens